# Is it possible to forward messages in Gmail to an unattended mailbox?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-forwarding

I need to add a number of filters to a Google business email account I use to receive job applications. The filters need to send certain emails to unattended mailboxes that are used to identify the source of the job application. Gmail seems to need to verify forwarding email addresses. Is there a way around this?

I am currently using Outlook rules to do this but this has to be set up on each machine. It would be much easier if it could be done on Gmail.

Comment: I certainly hope there isn't. What a great way to spam someone by proxy.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to set a filter that automatically forwards the email to another address, then yes, you need to verify ownership of that forwarded email address.

A workaround, if you own another domain/email provider (eg. example.com), is to set up a forwarder at this domain. eg. "forwarder@example.com" simply forwards to "joe@intended-recipient.com". Your Gmail filter then forwards to "forwarder@example.com". You still off course need to verify "forwarder@example.com", which acts as the *middle man*.

If you only need to identify the *source* of the email, then why can you not simply assign a label?